# CSS :not ? Select all div not but not a selection of them

Tags: css

HI, i need to select all div in dom without a selection of them.
How can i do ?
It's right ?

```
div:not(#a, #b, #c..){
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the preference rules of CSS to override the setting for specific elements. Example:

```
div {
  display: none;
}
#a, #b, #c {
  display: block;
}
```